Is it possible to add a custom transition to TabView children when page changes?
I have a controlled Tab view like this
    TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
      IntroductionView().tag(1)
      HomeView().tag(2)
      SettingsView().tag(3)
      ProfileView().tag(4)
    }

I want to add transition to each of the views when activeTab changes, say simple cross fade of opacity?
Tried something along the lines of
    TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
      IntroductionView().tag(1).transition(.opacity)
      HomeView().tag(2).transition(.opacity)
      SettingsView().tag(3).transition(.opacity)
      ProfileView().tag(4).transition(.opacity)
    }
    .animation(.smooth, value: activeTab)


But this seems to have no effect. There are some answers like this one that add some kind of scrollable / slide animation via .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
modifier, but that's not exactly what I'm after.
Perhaps there is a way to utilize / extend UIKit to add a cross fade transition?

TabView just uses a UITabBarController under the hood, so you can introspect it and do something like this. Or you can write your own UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapping UITabBarController. Or make your own tab view purely using SwiftUI. There are many options.

A native TabView does not support transitions. But it is easy to replace the TabView with a ZStack + custom tab bar and use if/else to switch content. Then you can use any transition you like.

@BenzyNeez I was doing that beforehand, but the issue is it does not preserve state of the view that you "left" i.e. if it was scrolled for example.

To preserve state, it needs to stay in memory. So instead of using if/else, you could just change opacity to make one view visible and the others invisible. This would still allow an opacity transition, but not a slide transition. For sliding panels, this answer might help.

@BenzyNeez Wouldn't this harm performance? That's one of the reasons I opted to use TabView {}, I was under impression that it somehow offloads the view but preserves its state. If that's not the case, I could indeed just opt to use ZStack and toggle opacity / disable views

You might be right about TabView maintaining state while still offloading the views. I tried a test with some List as child content and the scroll position was preserved, even though isAppear and isDisappear are called when switching. However, I do not know the extent to which the views are actually off-loaded and resources freed.

If you want to be able to specify a Transition for each of the tabs using a view modifier, like you did in the example code, it is best to write your own TabView.
Here is an adapted version of the custom "tab view" I wrote here, that makes the tabs look more like tabs. I have also added a tabTransition modifier to allow you to choose a Transition.
struct CustomTabView<Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: Selection
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        Extract(content) { views in
            ForEach(views) { view in
                if view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab {
                    view
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .transition(view[TabTransitionTrait.self])
                }
            }
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                    ForEach(views) { view in
                        Group {
                            if let label = view[CustomTabItemTrait.self] {
                                label
                            } else {
                                Text("Unnamed")
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if let selection = view.id(as: Selection.self) {
                                selectedTab = selection
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(
                            view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab ?
                                AnyShapeStyle(Color.accentColor) : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1))
                        )
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        _trait(CustomTabItemTrait.self, AnyView(content()))
    }
}

struct CustomTabItemTrait: _ViewTraitKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyView? = nil
}

extension View {
    func tabTransition<T: Transition>(_ transition: T) -> some View {
        _trait(TabTransitionTrait.self, AnyTransition(transition))
    }
}

struct TabTransitionTrait: _ViewTraitKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyTransition = .identity
}

// MARK: View Extractor - https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor

public struct Extract<Content: View, ViewsContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let views: (Views) -> ViewsContent

    public init(_ content: Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = { content }
        self.views = views
    }

    public init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = content
        self.views = views
    }

    public var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(
            UnaryViewRoot(views: views),
            content: content
        )
    }
}

fileprivate struct UnaryViewRoot<Content: View>: _VariadicView_UnaryViewRoot {
    let views: (Views) -> Content

    func body(children: Views) -> some View {
        views(children)
    }
}

public struct ExtractMulti<Content: View, ViewsContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let views: (Views) -> ViewsContent

    public init(_ content: Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = { content }
        self.views = views
    }

    public init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = content
        self.views = views
    }

    public var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(
            MultiViewRoot(views: views),
            content: content
        )
    }
}

fileprivate struct MultiViewRoot<Content: View>: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
    let views: (Views) -> Content

    func body(children: Views) -> some View {
        views(children)
    }
}

public typealias Views = _VariadicView.Children

Example usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    var body: some View {
        CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab.animation()) {
            Color.blue
                .id(0) // you must use .id instead of .tag to specify the selection value
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("Baz", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tabTransition(.push(from: .leading))
            
            Color.yellow
                .id(1)
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("Foo", systemImage: "globe")
                }
                .tabTransition(.push(from: .bottom))
            
            Color.green
                .id(2)
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("Bar", systemImage: "rectangle")
                }
                .tabTransition(.opacity)
        }
    }
}

This does not preserve the states of each tab, like scroll position. If this is undesirable, you cannot use the transition modifier (and hence the built-in Transitions). You would need to do your own animation for the transitions. For example, an opacity animation would be implemented with .opacity:
// in CustomTabView.body
ZStack {
    ExtractMulti(content) { views in
        ForEach(views) { view in
            view
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .opacity(view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
    // the rest of the tab bar goes here...
}

For a moving transition, you might give each tab an .offset depending on whether it is selected (view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab) or not, and so on.

I will give this a shot, thank you. At first glance I have 1 followup question, would this preserve view states like scroll position when user navigates away and back to the tab?

@Ilja No, because the transition modifier only animates when the view disappears/appears. You can easily change this to preserve view states by using .opacity to control visibility, instead of the if view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab. But then you are limited to an opacity transition. In other words, you cannot use the built-in Transitions, and would have to do your own animations.

Thank you, accepted this as the solution indeed worked, but in the end opted for using TabView as it comes, it seems to offer a lot of optimizations and state persistance out of the box than I could replicate with conditional rendering or opacity + zstack for example
